# Invalidate Symfony2 HttpCache across domains

Tags: php, symfony, http-caching

Multiple domains are pointed to the same Symfony2 REST API backend:

- `example.com/api/post/abc`
- `embed.example.com/api/post/abc`
- `whitelabeled.com/api/post/abc`

The goal is to have the same response for all the domains while using [Symfony HttpCache](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#introduction-to-http-caching). It's true for initial `GET` request.

However when I send `PUT` request  to `example.com/api/post/abc`, Symfony automatically invalidates this route for `example.com` domain. But it does not invalidate the route for other domains. Now when I do `GET` request I left with:

- `example.com/api/post/abc` - Response with latest data
- `embed.example.com/api/post/abc` - Old cached response
- `whitelabeled.com/api/post/abc` - Old cached response

What is the way to automatically invalidate the response across all existing domains for a particular route?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can try use FOSHttpCacheBundle http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/features/invalidation.html and invalidate cache via its service at PUT controller action

Comment: Do you know if that works with Symfony HttpCache, it currently says Varnish&Nginx?

Comment: Looks like it can   "Symfony comes with a built-in reverse proxy written in PHP, known as HttpCache. While it is certainly less efficient than using Varnish or Nginx, it can still provide considerable performance gains over an installation that is not cached at all. It can be useful for running an application on shared hosting for instance (see the Symfony HttpCache documentation).

You can use features of this library with the Symfony HttpCache. The basic concept is to use event subscribers on the HttpCache class."

Comment: http://foshttpcachebundle.readthedocs.org/en/latest/features/symfony-http-cache.html